# How to take a previously input integer and find the odds evens and zeros in a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

One of my modules requires me to take a previously entered integer and find the evens, odds and zeros. But my code is giving me some flawed results. A little help would be appreciated

```
def oez(num):
        s = 0
        count_odd = int (0)
        count_even = int (0)
        count_zero= int (0)
        while (num > 0):
            r = num % 10
            s= s+r
            num = num //10
            if num % 2 == 0:
                count_even=+1
            elif num % 10 == 0:
                count_zero=+1
            else:
                count_odd=+ 1
        print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
        print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
        print("Number of Zeroes:", count_zero)
```

Comment: What results is it giving that you don't want? What results are you expecting?

Comment: if i were to enter 11 it says i have 1 odd and 1 zero and no evens

Comment: What is part of a menu? What is what you get? What is what you want to get?

Comment: and if i were to enter 12 as the integer it still says i have 1 odd and 1 zero

Comment: 12 sure looks like 1 odd and 1 even to me.....

Comment: You want to know if the *digits* are odd, even, or zero?

Comment: yes I want to know if the digits are odd, even, or zero, kind of new to this whole programming thing

Comment: No problem. See the various solutions below. Some are more simpler than others at the expense of performance. Note you should specify whether you want the digit 0 to count as zero AND even or just as zero.

Answer (score 1):

because im feeling evil this morning here is a cool solution (the target number is `551240`)

```
odd,even,zed = map(len,map(''.join,zip(*re.findall("([13579])|([2468])|(0)","551240"))))
print(odd,even,zed)
```

of coarse a more sane solution is probably just to check each digit

```
odd=even=zed=0
for digit in "551240":
   if digit in "2468": even += 1
   elif digit in "13579": odd += 1
   elif digit == "0": zed += 1
```

Comment: Well it works great. But how would you get it to work for a previously input integer

Answer (score 0):

```
def oez(num):
        count_odd = 0
        count_even = 0
        count_zero = 0
        for letter in str(num): # Cast the input as a string
            digit = int(letter) # Cast the character as an int (0-9)
            if digit == 0:
                count_zero += 1
            elif digit % 2 == 0:
                count_even += 1
            elif digit == 0:
                count_odd += 1
            else:
                print("Invalid character")
        print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
        print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
        print("Number of Zeroes:", count_zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def oez(num):
    num_repr = str(int(num))
    zeroes = len([digit for digit in num_repr if digit == "0"])
    evens = len([digit for digit in num_repr if int(digit) % 2 == 0])
    odds = len([digit for digit in num_repr if int(digit) % 2 == 1])
    print("evens: %d" % evens)
    print("zeroes: %d" % zeroes)
    print("odds: %d" % odds)
```